# ValueError: Cannot query "username": Must be "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I recently migrated my project to a new host using nginx/gunicorn instead of Apache2.
The project has a custom user model with User and Profile classes (among others).

The same project runs without error in the old production.  But in the new environment
we got ValueError when a registered user updated his profile.
The code are exactly the same. However we upgraded some packages, e.g. Django 3.0.7 to 3.0.8, and may be a few others that seems harmless.

Here is the error output

```
Internal Server Error: /update_profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/myproject/accounts/views.py", line 183, in update_profile
    myprofile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1354, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1381, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1288, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1123, in check_related_objects
    self.check_query_object_type(value, opts, field)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1104, in check_query_object_type
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot query "xxx": Must be "User" instance.
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /update_profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/myproject/accounts/views.py", line 183, in update_profile
    myprofile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1354, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1381, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1288, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1123, in check_related_objects
    self.check_query_object_type(value, opts, field)
  File "/webapps/orchidroots/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1104, in check_query_object_type
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot query "xxx": Must be "User" instance.
```

The view method that threw the error:

```
def update_profile(request):
    user = auth.get_user(request)    <------- We also tried user = request.user
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    myprofile = Profile.objects.get(user=user) <------ error here
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile_obj = form.save(commit=False)
```

Here is the models (simplified):

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username  = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    fullname =  models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255) #,  unique=True,)
    tier = models.ForeignKey(Tier, null=True, default=1, db_column='tier',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    confirm_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photo_credit_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    current_credit_name = models.OneToOneField(Photographer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True)
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',null=True,blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,db_column='country',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True, blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField( blank=True, default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I hope someone could help solving this mystery.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Get the request user instance and filter the profile model using that instance

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you could check what type of data you have in variable `user` - ie. `print( type(user)  )` - if error says it is not `User` then you will see what you get.

Comment: @furas   Sorry, I haven't figured out how to coax gunicorn to output full log yet.

Comment: Ok.  I got gunicorn to oputput detailed error.  See update above

Comment: Thank you both SEJ and  furas who show me the light!!!